# In javascript, need to perform sum of dynamic array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dynamic array and I need to perform a sum of it.

```
 {ClientName: "A", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0}
{ClientName: "b", Alex: 0, Da: 0, Cal: 4}
{ClientName: "c", Alex: 1, Da: 0, Cal: 5}
{ClientName: "d", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0}
```

in this array, client name is fixed but other columns like Alex, Da, Cal are dynamic and will vary. i need to create a generic function in typescript where output will be like this.

```
{ClientName: "Total", Alex: 5, Da: 0, Cal: 9}
```

Comment: please add an attempt.

Comment: “Columns are dynamic” means the property names are arbitrary and could be anything? Or is there a certain set of possible column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Idea:

- Uses `Object.keys` to get all enumerable keys.
- Loop over them ans set them to default if not found. Then add current object's value.
- Since you need hardcoded value for `ClientName`, you can set it either in loop or set it after loop.

```js
const data = [
  {ClientName: "A", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0},
  {ClientName: "b", Alex: 0, Da: 0, Cal: 4},
  {ClientName: "c", Alex: 1, Da: 0, Cal: 5},
  {ClientName: "d", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0},
]

const output = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  Object
  .keys(item)
  .forEach((key) => {
    acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + item[key]
  });
  acc.ClientName = 'Total'
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the wanted values.

```js
var data = [{ ClientName: "A", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0 }, { ClientName: "b", Alex: 0, Da: 0, Cal: 4 }, { ClientName: "c", Alex: 1, Da: 0, Cal: 5 }, { ClientName: "d", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0 }],
    total = data.reduce((a, { ClientName, ...b }) => Object.assign(
        {},
        a,
        { ClientName: 'total' },
        ...Object.entries(b).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: (a[k] || 0) + v }))
    ));
    
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work as long as all keys besides ClientName are defined as numbers

```
arr.reduce((sumObject, item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if(key === 'ClientName'){
      return false
    }

    if(!sumObject[key]) {
      sumObject[key] = item[key]
    } else {
      sumObject[key] += item[key]
    }
  })

   return sumObject
}, {ClientName: 'Total'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate with `reduce` to generate single output and to merge the key count you can use `Object.keys` and `map` will allow you to iterate over your object keys. Also added one dynamic key `Abc: 9` just to verify the result.

```js
const object = [{
    ClientName: "A",
    Alex: 2,
    Da: 0,
    Cal: 0
  },
  {
    ClientName: "b",
    Alex: 0,
    Da: 0,
    Cal: 4
  },
  {
    ClientName: "c",
    Alex: 1,
    Da: 0,
    Cal: 5
  },
  {
    ClientName: "d",
    Alex: 2,
    Da: 0,
    Cal: 0,
    Abc: 9
  },
]

const result = object.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  Object.keys(currentValue).map((indexKey) => {
    accumulator[indexKey] = (accumulator[indexKey] || 0) + currentValue[indexKey]
  });
  accumulator.ClientName = "Total";
  return accumulator;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly same as mine. Please check other answers before posting

Comment: Yes I do agree, but It seems similar but not exactly, See in you code there is `forEach` which is less optimized than `.map` which is being used in my solution. Anyways I have already voted up for your solution.

Comment: using a map without return statement is so much worse. Also i don't think map is more optimised compared to forEach but that discussion can be done later

Answer (score -1):

```
 let arr = [
    {ClientName: "A", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0},
    {ClientName: "b", Alex: 0, Da: 0, Cal: 4},
    {ClientName: "c", Alex: 1, Da: 0, Cal: 5},
    {ClientName: "d", Alex: 2, Da: 0, Cal: 0}
];

let output = arr.reduce((curr, next) => {
   return {ClientName: "Total", Alex: (curr.Alex + next.Alex ), Da: (curr.Da + next.Da), Cal: (curr.Cal + next.Cal)};
});

console.log(output);
```

Check this can get the answer simply

Comment: OP is looking for a solutions that handles *Dynamic columns*

Comment: yes you are right , it shoud not work for dynamic columns.thank you,